# Xamarin Forms - Authentication with WebAPI - Auth attribute for Pages - Store data

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just started write my first mobile application  with xamarin. 
(I'm web developer - .net asp mvc/ web api and all client.....)

So I just try understand how i should to work with mobile authentication?

I'm already can send request to webapi and get access token

(http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/how-to-register-and-authenticate-with-web-api-2-and-owin/)

Now I have 2 question - its -

where to save access token??

I have 2 ideas -

```
Static class User with static string accessCode property
```

or

```
Application.Current.Properties["AccessToken"] = "";
```

What is the best way to save for current ""**session**" ??

And Second question is - i want to save user login - for next time user dont will need enter login/password........ so i need tp work with his db ???
Can you give me tip - how to save username and password?? 
I need encrupt his password??

Sorry for English grammar guys

Comment: What do you mean by "session"?  That isn't very well defined in terms of apps.If Android decides to suspend your app and resume it later, do you want the user to have to log in again?

Comment: No - if he did 1 time login - i wont ask user login again till he dont do logout

Comment: Then you want to store the access token in Application.Current.Properties, which is persistent storage. Making it a static member variable on the class will mean the user has to log in each time the app is started. Also, it is better to store the access token than the username and password.